# Do elementary functions came from differential equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions

I've read recently, that just like Laguerre or Bessel functions elementary functions also came from solutions to ordinary differential equations.
Is that true ? and also how that this evolved ? What are those simple ODEs ? i could'nt find any kind of source to read from about this topic.

Comment: Which elementary functions do you mean? Exponentials and sine and cosine satisfy some ODEs - is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "came from solutions to ordinary differential equations"- some of them were known much earlier than the development of the theory of ODEs I think. But one could associate some initial value problems to some elementary functions- Most famous would be $f'(t)=f(t), f(0)=1$ and the solution of course is $f(t)=e^t$, another famous one (two?) would be $y''=-y$ with initial value of $y(0)=0$ or $y(0)=1$

Comment: In exact translation in my lecture notes there were written that elementary functions like trigonometric exponential logarithmic or polynomials "were created" from solutions to differential equations.